# Counting not equal strings in array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, count

I want to count all the  different string elements in an array. 
So my input would be:

```
5 Lemon Orange Lemon Mango Lemon
```

And the output should be this:

```
3
```

The problem with my code is, that my code counts all the elements, and not just the different and I can't figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;   
    cin >> N;
    string Tname;
    string data[N];
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        cin >> Tname;
        data[i] = Tname;
    }

    for(int l = 0; l<N; l++)
    {
        int k = 0;
        while(k<N && (data[l] != data[k]))
        {
            k++;
        }
        if(k<N)
        {
            counter += 1;
        }

    }
    cout << counter << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This `string data[N];` is not valid C++.

Comment: I suppose just loading a `std::unordered_set<std::string>` and reporting the `size()` upon loop completion is out of bounds. [Like this](https://pastebin.com/rycjb8nh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is algorithmic:  every item is equal to itself,  which will end your k loop prematurely. In addition, you only increment when the item is repeated.

I propose you to change the loops, so not to compare every items with every other items, but only items, to items previously processed:

```
for(int l = 0; l<N; l++)
{
    int k = 0;
    while(k<l &&  data[l] != data[k])  // only previous items
    {
        k++;
    }
    if(k==l)   // if no identical, we can add this one
    {
        cout<<l<<" "<<data[l]<<endl;
        counter += 1;
    }
}
```

**Not related:** variable length arrays are not legal C++ even if some mainstream compilers accept it. I'd suggest to use a vector to emulate this feature: `vector<string> data(N);`

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/UKuE3z)

Comment: This doesn't fix the logic.  This is counting 3 lemons and it just happens to be the same as the answer.

Comment: @super oops, indeed.  I've edited, keeping the loop structure, but only looking at previous items

Comment: Yeah, thank you, this resolved my code, and now I understand what was the problem in my logic. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Benedek glad to know that it helped :-) Thanks for this feedback

Answer (score 0):

if i understand well your problem , you want the value that has the max appearances in the array, some modifications are needed to achieve this :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;   
    cin >> N;
    string Tname;
    string data[N];
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        cin >> Tname;
        data[i] = Tname;
    }

    int tempCounter; // a temporary counter for each item of the array .
    for(int l = 0; l < N; l++)
    {
        tempCounter = 0;
        int k = 0;
        while(k<N)
        {
            if(data[l] == data[k])
                tempCounter++;
            k++;
        }
        if(tempCounter > counter) // if the new counter is higher than the counter 
            counter = tempCounter;
    }
    cout << counter << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not the max appearances. I wanted to count all the different elements in the array. Sorry if my explanation wasn't accurate. But thanks for the help, I think i learn from that as well.

Answer (score 0):

the last if should be if(k+1==N)

because you all the time stop the while before the k reach N

and k must start from l

Your logic is, you add 1 to the counter if it is not in the list's remaining part
But the code check the full list so you never count thw world whitch in the list twice.